# подскажите есть готовый модуль для php интеграция с 1с

Tags: php, cms, 1с, интернет-магазин

должен сделать обмен между 1С и сайтом.
этот магазин где должен интегравать написано с нуля не используется CMS,
подскажите есть готовый модуль для  интеграция с 1с.
Сайт написано с php & mysqli

Comment: http://www.gebekovas.ru/index.php/programmy/insturmenty/adapter-1c/opisanie-i-ustanvoka

Comment: На самописных движках обычно пишут парсеры самостоятельно, исходя из передаваемых данных (как 1С-ник Вам xml создаст). Заодно и руку набьете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот  [здесь](http://v8.1c.ru/edi/edi_stnd/131/) можно прочесть ответ

А вообще есть мнение — они все сделали так, чтобы в этом либо никто не разобрался, либо единицы, потратив кучу времени на гадание на кофейной гуще.

Все-таки продажи 1С-Битрикс куда важнее, чем дела программистов-конкурентов.

Answer (score 0):

Есть [Metadata.js](http://www.oknosoft.ru/metadata/) — Javascript-реализация функционала, который вы ищете. Но это не php )

Comment: Дайте более развёрнтый ответ. Например, опишите функционал приведённый в ссылке.